# Setup VueJS In Subdirectory

Tags: vuejs2, babeljs

I have a VueJS app that I would like to deploy, i'm currently running `npm run build` to build the app, however I want this app to be in a subdirectory of my website.

The problem i'm having is when building the app, it creates the wrong paths to the css and javascript file.

I have tried using `root` inside `babel.config.js` but it gives me an error when I try to build it (`root is only allowed in root programmatic options`).

Anyone know how I can go about fixing this issue? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the `publicPath` and `base` options:

https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath
https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base

Possibly you will also need to adjust your webserver config if using history mode:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Comment: Hi! Yeah it ended up being history mode, thanks for the answer. :D